# K2 Joomla: show the last modified article in home page

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-k2

I think this should be easy but cannot make it work ... I'm using k2 on Joomla for handling articles and i want to show on the home page the last modified blog post ... i've create a Home category under which i've put some subcategories, bound to several K2 article items. In the home menu item i've created a "Latest item from users or categories" that correctly select the last 1 item. If i change the modified date to another article, i do not see it in the home page.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you show the code you're using to retrieve the article please?

Comment: Code is embedded in k2. I've just set "Latest items from users or categories" and would like to know how to set ordering without modifying core files.

Comment: What about using "Categories" instead of "latest items ...." and choosing "Latest modified" in Item ordering ? and of course limiting it to one article.